# Sending Auto Cut in EPSON Thermal Printer from Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, thermal-printer

I am trying to use Crystal Report for printing to EPSON Thermal Printer TM-T88IV using Windows Driver (EPSON Advanced Printer Driver 4.52ce). OPOS was not chosen for certain reasons. I am using SAP Crystal Report 2011, though I have Visual Studio 2010 installed as well.

The printer setting for PaperSource (Printer - Printing Preference - Document Settings - Paper Source) is set to DOCUMENT[Feed, Cut]. The report is cutting fine at the end of the report.

However, my requirement is to have a report section (e.g. a Report Footer) which will be be cut from the upper part of the report. A typical scenario is to print free parking tickets at the end of a Point Of Sale Receipt. The ticket though part of the same receipt, is autocut from the upper part of the receipt for the convenience of the customer.

I have studied about ControlA fonts and had seen a reference at http://gtts.ehu.es/TWiki/pub/Main/WebNotify/uni-mini-manual.pdf which made me believe that ControlA fonts can be used from MS Word 2007 for auto cutting in between a document, wherever I want. However, that is not working.

If anybody can guide me with autocut from MS Word 2007 with EPSON TM-T88IV that would be of great help. If it works I believe it should work from Crystal as well.

Thanks in advance.

- Rajarshi

Comment: The programming language you are doing this in is?

Comment: I am using Crystal Reports 2011 Report Design tool. It is a standaolne report design tool. It does have a language of its own, but only when I am using formula.
I need the solution based on either Crystal Report 2011 or MS Word 2007/2010. If Word can send an AutoCut with Control fonts to Themal printer, I think Crystal would be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Set the report's printer to the desired Epson printer (File | Page Setup
- Add a Text Object to the desired location in your report (maybe a group footer).
- Add a single 'F' to the Text Object (without the single quotes)
- Change the Text Object's font to 'control'; set the font size to 10

Print the report and see if it works.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I did (in a Report footer section) but it did not work. I tried both 'control' and 'controlA' fonts. None worked. Any clues?

Comment: Is there anything else in the RF section?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, the page cutting and till drawer opening worked fine through the old ActiveX control but failed to work through the .NET crystal viewer.

The solution is to create a WordPad (RTF) document, put your control character D or A or F etc... into that document in the 'control' font size 10, then back in crystal insert the WordPad document as an OLE object into the Crystal Print.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with EPSON TM20 receipt printer. Change the settings of printer from Printer - Printing Preference - Document Settings - Paper Source)  DOCUMENT[Feed, Cut] to Page [Feed, Cut]. And test it.

At present I am using PHP and HTML to print the receipts to the thermal printer. I added these lines

. It works smoothly.